# Difference between ScalaCheck Arbitrary[T] and Scalacheck Gen[T]

Tags: scala, scalacheck

In my tests I am making quite an extensive usage of Specs2 + ScalaCheck and there are some patterns to factor out. I still haven't found out if my functions should use an Arbitrary[T] or a Gen[T], since they are very similar:

```
sealed abstract class Arbitrary[T] {
  val arbitrary: Gen[T]
}
```

Would a function signature looks like that:

```
maxSizedIntervalArbitrary[A,B](implicit ordering:Ordering[A], genStart:Arbitrary[A], genEnd:Arbitrary[B]):Arbitrary[TreeMap[A,B]]
```

or should I work at the `Gen` abstraction level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you need Arbitraries in scalacheck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111106/why-do-you-need-arbitraries-in-scalacheck)

Answer (score 4):

I'd say do both:

```
def maxSizedIntervalArbitrary[A,B](genStart:Gen[A], genEnd:Gen[B])(implicit ordering:Ordering[A]):Gen[TreeMap[A,B]]

implicit def maxSizedIntervalArbitrary[A,B](implicit ordering:Ordering[A], genStart:Arbitrary[A], genEnd:Arbitrary[B]):Arbitrary[TreeMap[A,B]] = 
  Arbitrary(maxSizedIntervalArbitrary(arbitrary[A], arbitrary[B]))
```

`Arbitrary` is used to supply implicit `Gen`s, basically, so this allows to use both `forAll` variants with explicit `Gen` and with implicit `Arbitrary`. I don't think non-`implicit` `Arbitrary` is ever useful.

Comment: Makes sense. What about Arbitrary conflicts ?(There are implicits arbitrary defined in Arbitrary companion objects which are making my life impossible)

Comment: In this case I think you may have to avoid `Arbitrary` and use only `Gen` version. To minimize explicit passing of `Gen`s, you can add an overload taking `implicit Arbitrary` and still returning `Gen` as well.