# Scalacheck set-size Array Generators

Tags: arrays, scala, properties, automated-tests, scalacheck

I am attempting to make a ScalaCheck matrix generator that will generate a 2D array/ matrix of a specified order (size/dim).  I started with the example on the tutorial, and simplified it (for prototyping--I understand I should use sized to be able to resize future generators) to

```
def matrix[ T ]( g: Gen[ T ] )( order: Int ): Gen[ Array[ Seq[ T ] ] ] =
  Gen.listOfN( order, Gen.listOfN( order, g ) ).map(_.toArray)
```

However, I could not get an Array[Array[T]] from this without putting in a ClassTag:

```
def matrix[ T : ClassTag]( g: Gen[ T ] )( order: Int ): Gen[ Array[ Seq[ T ] ] ] =
  Gen.listOfN( order, Gen.listOfN( order, g ) ).map(_.toArray)
```

Which I sort-of understand--I'm not that experienced in Scala.  In the process of getting there, I tried this:

```
def matrix2[ T : ClassTag]( g: Gen[ T ] )( order: Int ): Gen[ Array[ Array[ T ] ] ] =
  for {
    rowSeq <- Gen.listOfN( order, g )
    rowArray <- rowSeq.toArray
    seqOfRowArrays <- Gen.listOfN( order, rowArray)
    matrix <- seqOfRowArrays.toArray
  } yield matrix
```

but the compiler complained
    "type mismatch;  found   : Array[T]  required: org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[Array[T]]]"
on the rowArray line and
    "Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch;  found   : org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[T]]  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]"
on the seqOfRowArrays line.

My questions are:
1.  Is there a simpler way to get a defined size Array[Array[T]], ie some way to bound Arbitrary?
2.  What is wrong with the typing of the above for expression?
3.  When tests fail, how will I keep ScalaCheck from reducing the order during shrinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1: Don't worry about `Arbitrary` v. `Gen`. They are basically the same. There is a good answer explaining the distinctions between them here: [Why do you need Arbitraries in scalacheck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111106/why-do-you-need-arbitraries-in-scalacheck)

#2 You are mixing your monadic containers (`Gen` and `Array`) and scala is doing its best to combine them, and this gives you a confusing error.

To fix your type error, do this

```
def matrix2[ T : ClassTag]( g: Gen[ T ] )( order: Int ): Gen[ Array[ Array[ T ] ] ] =
  for {
    rowSeq <- Gen.listOfN( order, g )
    rowArray = rowSeq.toArray
    seqOfRowArrays <- Gen.listOfN( order, rowArray)
  } yield seqOfRowArrays.toArray
```

If you run this in the terminal you will notice something odd:

```
scala> matrix2(Gen.choose(1,10))(3)
res2: org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[Array[Int]]] = org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$6@4c93778e

scala> res2.sample
res3: Option[Array[Array[Int]]] = Some([[I@1dd38904)

scala> res3.foreach{a2 => a2.foreach{a => a.foreach{i => println(s" $i")}; println("\n")}}
 6
 10
 5


 6
 10
 5


 6
 10
 5
```

This only generates one row then repeats this same row throughout the matrix. My solution to this would be to use scalacheck to generate order^2 elements then group them into your 2D array structure after the fact. Here is a copy/paste from my Scala REPL where I did this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    def matrix2[T: ClassTag](g: Gen[T])(order: Int): Gen[Array[Array[T]]] = 
      Gen.listOfN(order*order, g).map { squareList =>
        squareList.toArray.grouped(order).toArray
      }


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

matrix2: [T](g: org.scalacheck.Gen[T])(order: Int)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[Array[T]]]

scala> matrix2(Gen.choose(1,10))(3)
res5: org.scalacheck.Gen[Array[Array[Int]]] = org.scalacheck.Gen$$anon$6@7519bc73

scala> res5.sample.foreach{a2 => a2.foreach{a => a.foreach{i => println(s" $i")}; println("\n")}}
 1
 9
 9


 7
 6
 10


 10
 2
 6
```

#3 The `order` will not change for this generator as you are using `listOfN` method which fixes the size of the collection. The example in the user guide only resizes because it uses the `Gen.sized` generator.